# Arbitrary order xparse e type arguments (embellishments)?

Tags: macros, xparse

Can I use xparse e-type arguments to redefine how subscripts and superscripts work for a command (e.g., make \mybeta put all sub/super scripts in parens)?  I tried defining

```
 \NewDocumentCommand{\mybeta}{e_e^}{\beta_{(#1)}^{(#2)}}
```

And it seems to work fine if I place them in the order the arguments are specified but not when I try

```
 \mybeta^{n}_{s}
```

where I get a double subscript warning when I want $\beta^{(n)}_{(s)}$

I'm guessing that maybe I need to use e{_^} as the argument specification but if I do that how do I tell the _ and ^ arguments apart or recover them?  Or is there a different/better way I should be going about this and I've misunderstood the embellishments entirely?

Comment: Use 'e{_^}' to specify the embellishments. It should "just work."

Comment: Huh, it does.  That's so weird...so you never use multiple e arguments in specifying your command.

Comment: @PeterGerdes We tried a few ways to express how to have 'mixed order' arguments: the `e{_^}` one was by far the best

Comment: @JosephWright It's perfectly clear now that I understand it but I just assumed that it would be written as e{_}e{^} rather than e{_^} and I got lost when I tried to dig through the code.  Thanks for your reply and the excellent work on xparse.  I really love NDC

Comment: @JosephWright  By the way is there any easy way to do arbitrary order delimited arguments, e.g., suppose I have exactly one ( ) argument and want it to be picked up wherever it appears.  I don't suppose there is an easy way to do this (or the embellishments wouldn't be limited to picking up just the next unit (group? token?).  And yes I know that's *usually* a bad idea but I'm translating math notation that already uses brackets,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is, as you predicted, to use `e{_^}` in your argument specification. The order of the embellishments doesn’t matter. And yes, it’s amazing that it works!

Comment: Not quite what I predicted.  I'd assumed that each e specification corresponded to one argument so e{_^} would scoop up whatever follows *either* an ^ or _ and assign it to #1.  Guess not.  Thanks , this is super useful.  I'll leave my answer up since you commented on it.

Comment: I think we wrote them simultaneously!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently (thanks to @LateXeraXeTal)  you just use

```
 \NewDocumentCommand{\mybeta}{e{_^}}{\beta_{(#1)}^{(#2)}}
```

I admit I'm a bit confused as to why you don't use multiple e argument type specifiers to do this.  Would one ever use multiple e type arguments?

Comment: I personally have not seen multiple e{} arguments used, but that doesn’t meant it’s not possible. Hopefully one of the LaTeX3 devs can comment.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think that if you did, e.g., `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{e{^}e{_}}`, you would be requiring the embellishments to come in that order. That being said, and again I haven't tested this, you could, theoretically do `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{e{^}e{^}}` and have two (optional) embellishments. Or you could allow embellishments in different places in an argument list with mandatory and optional arguments.